# How to send a job to Spark on Kubernetes. External scheduler cannot be instantiated

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have started a Minikube cluster but when I make spark-submit, job get an error.

My command:

```
bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://192.168.99.101:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-test --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=5 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.0.jar
```

And I get the following error:

> 2019-03-13 18:26:57 ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing
>   SparkContext. org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler
>   cannot be instantiated    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2794)
>     ...30 more 
>   Caused by:
>   io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure
>   executing: GET at:
>   https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/spark-test-1552501611130-driver.
>   Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access.
>   Service account may have been revoked. pods
>   "spark-test-1552501611130-driver" is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "pods" in
>   API group "" in the namespace "default".  ... 30 more

Comment: Can you please let us know spark settings for kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create ServiceAccount in Kubernetes. It can be done if you download the YAML config from this [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/885aa553c5e8f478b370f8a733102b67f6cd2d99/resource-managers/kubernetes/integration-tests/dev/spark-rbac.yaml)

And then run

```
kubectl apply -f spark-rbac.yaml
```

The YAML file will create the namespace and ServiceAccount, which are needed for Spark on Kubernetes.
However, you also need to modify your spark-submit command to be like:

```
bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://192.168.99.101:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-test --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-sa \
--conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.0.jar
```

Comment: I also have included the newly created service account but I still got the same error. Any suggestion for it?